# Validations not working after downgrade from mvc4 to mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have written a web application with asp.net mvc4 but because of some reasons I was forced to downgrade it to mvc3.Every thing is OK now but client side validations.
I loaded these files in my _Layout just after JQuery1.7:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And also this:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
```

Even I loaded the followings in all of my views again:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

But its not working.I mean it works but after refreshing the page!
When I click on submit button, after a refresh the page shows my view model data annotations validation errors!
What is wrong here exactly?!

Comment: Is client side validation enable in Web.Config?

Comment: Yes.Its enabled.I have checked every thing thousands of times @MohammadRB.:(

Answer (score 0):

Damn it.:-|

I found the issue after a one day of wasting time.

I changed the version of JQuery to 1.8 and it works now.